# Git on Windows Kerberos Authentication Failure

Tags: git

I have git installed on windows (latest version 2.20.1), but when I try and run git push I get the error
Kerberos authentication failed.  Password:

however it never gives me a chance to enter the password.  Within a second or so it continues with  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

How can I fix this on my windows machine?  I looked in credential manager and there is nothing git there.  This is an internal git repo (ssh://git.corp.com/repo is what I get when I do git remote -v) and not github.

Local and System Config:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://git.corp.com/pkg/repo
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "mainline"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/mainline
[credential]
        helper = store
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling GIT allows me to at least enter the password, however it still doesn't work with my current password.  I get:

```
<username>@git.corp.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).
```

Comment: klist shows 18 valid kerberos tickets.

Comment: What is in your global configuration ?  Open the git bash in windows and type git config —global -e

Comment: git config --global -e just shows [winupdater] recentlyseenversion 2.20.1.windows.1 in the file

Comment: The local and system config files are both identical and they have much more in them.

Comment: You can add your user.name and user.email there, also, the GitHub url should be https, if you use ssh it won’t ask you for username and password, when you use https it will ask you for username and password

Comment: Again, this is an internal git repository site, not github.

Comment: My bad, I was on my mobile and missed that part, at this point I am just guessing because I do not know what configuration is there, but first I'd change the url from https to ssh or viceversa to make sure that's not the problem, or if you have to use ssh I'd follow this guide to set up SSH auth in Git Bash for Windows
https://gist.github.com/bsara/5c4d90db3016814a3d2fe38d314f9c23

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer ended up being that I needed to fix a couple of settings on my PuTTy default settings.  The first thing I realized was that when I re-installed I didn't choose PuTTy the first time.  The second time I did, but the default settings had been changed to try using SSH1 and not SSH2 and the store needed the Microsoft SSPI DLL as the first on the list and it wasn't.

Comment: This would be a good question and answer if you gave more specifics about what the problems were and what you changed to fix them.  That would be helpful for people who have similar problems that they need to resolve.  As it stands, this question and answer is not likely to be helpful to others to resolve their problems.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer is not accurate. I have the exact same problem, and I cannot understand how PuTTY is related to the git client for windows.

Comment: http://blog.davidegrayson.com/2013/04/git-and-putty-in-windows.html#:~:text=Git%20spawns%20a%20new%20plink%20process%20with%20two,from%20plink%20is%20usefully%20redirected%20to%20your%20shell.  read the last part to understand how putty is related to GIT.  Not sure why my answer is downvoted because you don't know how putty is related.

Comment: PuTTY is not needed at all for usual Git usage, and Git is not needed at all for usual PuTTY usage. They're usually unrelated. I'm sorry for the downvote, but by writing "I needed to fix a couple of setting" isn't of any help for anyone. Imagine a person who reads this and doesn't know anything of the eventual relation between the two tools.

Comment: except I outlined the settings I need to change, so imagine how I tell you what I had to change being the answer to my question.

Comment: The answer has been downvoted because it doesn't explain why the issue in Putty was affecting Git for Windows. Putty is not needed for using Git for Windows...